# any way to replace yywrap definition? arguments, etc

Tags: c, flex-lexer, lex

You can replace yylex and pass your own arguments, is there any simple way to do this with yywrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are building an ordinary non-reentrant scanner, you can define `yywrap` as a macro. That macro could expand to a call to an arbitrary function with arbitrary arguments. (In this scenario, most of the things you could plausibly pass to your wrap function are globals, but it could be useful to pass through arguments passed to `yylex`.)

However, you need to put the macro definition in the inserted code at the top of yylex, because of the forward declaration of of `yywrap` in the generated code.

So your file might include:

```
%{
  #define YY_DECL   int yylex(Frobber* data)
  /* Forward declaration of mywrap 
  int mywrap(Frobber* data);
%}
%option ...

%%
  /* Indented lines before the first rule are inserted at the top of yylex
  #define yywrap() mywrap(data)
```

Defining `yywrap` as a macro is not explicitly permitted by the flex documentation, nor by Posix. So it should probably at least be accompanied with a comment, in case some later version does something which somehow prevents it from working. Putting the definition at the top of `yylex` is a bit of a hack, and may not be necessary with old lex versions.

There is a cleaner solution, if you are prepared to build a [re-entrant scanner](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Reentrant-Detail.html#Reentrant-Detail). In a reentrant scanner, `yywrap` will be automatically called with the same scanner argument that `yylex` will be called with. The scanner context object `scanner_t scanner` can be extended to include your own [extra data](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Extra-Data.html#Extra-Data), and that's usually  a better place to keep the sort of data which might plausibly be passed through to `yywrap`. There are other good reasons to chose to build a re-entrant scanner.

Comment: Oh interesting, so you can extend scanner_t?  See I thought that was opaque and I was passing my own with a scanner reference.  The "extra data" is for non-reentrant though right?  See with the reentrant, yywrap doesn't seem to be called with yylex's arguments... I'll have to double check that this afternoon.

Comment: @peterius: scanner_t has one extra data slot but you can make it whatever you want. That's only for **reentrant** scanners, and reentrant `yywrap` is called with the `scanner_t` argument.

Comment: Might depend on flex version, I didn't check.